# Best of Code Review 2016 - Exterminator category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2016 - Exterminator](/a/7107) category.

> *Answer that points out the most interesting obscure bug in the original code.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer, as well as a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post. Nominated answers must have a creation date in 2016. Downvotes don't count. Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to nominate my own answer here:

[CultureInfo with fallback routing to another language](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147192/cultureinfo-with-fallback-routing-to-another-language/150960#150960)

OP had built a `FallbackCultureInfo` which was designed to fall back to a different `CultureInfo` if the first one failed to localize the provided string. Simple, and this functionality is built into `CultureInfo` for a reason.

What OP failed to realize is that the `FallbackCultureInfo` would only work properly in a programme one time. I noticed this due to the `static` member in it.

What surprised me was the nature of the two bugs I discovered.

First: there was a bug if you provided a set of culture info's, then tried to construct a new fallback with another set, that included any culture info except the last of the first set. It basically skipped part of the process.

Second: this was more interesting. If you provided two `CultureInfo` items with the same *parent* (`en-US` and `en-UK`), then a third (or more) it would enter an infinite loop when traversing the parent. `en-US` -> `en` -> `en-UK` -> `en` -> `en-UK` -> ...

Both of these bugs were very curious, and created quite a havoc if the object was used incorrectly.